# How can I disable the F4 key from showing the items in a ComboBox

Tags: wpf, combobox, keyboard-shortcuts, key, keypress

You might not know this, but pressing the <kbd>F4</kbd> key on a `ComboBox` makes it's drop-down item list appear.  I believe this is the default behavior on Windows.

Does anyone know how to override this behavior in WPF (C#)?

I know that overriding default behavior is generally seen as bad practice, however in this case I have a rugged-device that runs XP Embedded.  It has a handful of prominent Function keys (<kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F6</kbd>) that need to trigger different events.  This works fine, however when focused over a `ComboBox` the events aren't triggered as the `ComboBox` drops down.

I have tried catching the `KeyDown` event both on the form and on the `ComboBox` and listening for the <kbd>F4</kbd> key, however it doesn't get this far as the key press must be handled at a lower level.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not positive about XP Embedded, but on regular ol' XP, this works.  Use PreviewKeyDown, and set e.Handled to true:

```
public MyWindowOrControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    cboTest.PreviewKeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(cboTest_PreviewKeyDown);
}

void cboTest_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.F4)
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Excellent, using PreviewKeyDown instead of KeyDown works.

Some information on the difference between the two:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/f05377aa-8894-4b51-a87e-2e2771f20cd6

http://blogs.msdn.com/jfoscoding/archive/2006/01/26/518181.aspx

Comment: I tried this on XP and for me, PreviewKeyDown never fires when pressing F4

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own ComboBox class and just inherit from the old one.. you should hopefully be able to override the keydown/up methods.